# When should the user for a newly created record be set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model, controller

When a user does something like create a blog post or upload a photo, a `user_id` gets set.

When should that be set? I've typically done it in the controller...

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.new(params[:blog])
  @blog.user_id = current_user.id
end
```

But is there a more appropriate place/way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the controller is a great place to do this. You're tying together application states (the currently logged in user and a newly created blog) which is what controllers are for. I would clean up that code a little bit though:

```
@blog = current_user.blogs.new(params[:blog])
```

No reason to have two lines when one will do!